# Automatic developer licence acquiring for Windows Store unit testing on a build server

Tags: .net, unit-testing, windows-8, windows-store-apps

For Windows Store applications, a developer licence is required to run the unit tests, which is fine for the individual developer on his personal machine.

But for a continuous integration process on a build server, we really need the ability to acquire the licence automatically.

Microsoft provides a command line tool, but it still creates a interactive window, which breaks the process.

```
TailoredDeploy.exe AcquireDeveloperLicense
```

So does anyone know of any other way to automatically acquire a developer licence? Spawning new build nodes is going to be hell if it needs manual setup via. VPN for each of them.

Comment: Just cook your own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj572812%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/7be92f16-7179-4d74-9915-c6f21e0f4c55

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem at all. It's still requesting user interaction.

Comment: Getting a machine to acquire the license is going to be difficult.  That would amount to being able to run Store apps without them being vetted by the store review process.  I suspect the only way to get ahead is to contact Microsoft Support and find out if there's a way to obtain a license that doesn't expire so quickly.

Comment: We've been investigating this on our team, too. We even asked our contact at Microsoft about it, but it doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: I work for Microsoft, and I'm asking internally as well as here :-) If we have to create a solution internally, I'll see if I can make it open source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was suggested to use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx), and here's what I've conjured up so far:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Automation;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\TailoredDeploy.exe", "AcquireDeveloperLicense");

        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        process.WaitForInputIdle();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        var agreementWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, process.Id));

        var iAgreeButton = agreementWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                          .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[2];

        var buttonPattern = iAgreeButton.GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(InvokePattern.Pattern.Id)) as InvokePattern;
        buttonPattern.Invoke();

        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("dllhost");

        var credentialsWindows = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children,
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, processes[0].Id));

        if (credentialsWindows[0].Current.Name == "Developer License")
        {
            var credentialsPane = credentialsWindows[0].FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                                       .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                                       .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                                       .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                                       .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

            var usernameTextBox = credentialsPane[3].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(ValuePattern.Pattern.Id)) as ValuePattern;
            usernameTextBox.SetValue("username@outlook.com");

            var passwordTextBox = credentialsPane[5].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(ValuePattern.Pattern.Id)) as ValuePattern;
            passwordTextBox.SetValue("password");

            var loginButton = credentialsPane[8].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(InvokePattern.Pattern.Id)) as InvokePattern;
            loginButton.Invoke();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);

            var finishUpProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("TailoredDeploy");

            var finishWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, finishUpProcesses[0].Id));

            var lastItems = finishWindow.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition)[0]
                                        .FindAll(TreeScope.Children, Condition.TrueCondition);

            var closeButton = lastItems[3].GetCurrentPattern(AutomationPattern.LookupById(InvokePattern.Pattern.Id)) as InvokePattern;
            closeButton.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

To use this, a `app.manifest` is required to run in elevated mode:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</asmv1:assembly>
```